# Swift dynamically instantiate the appropriate class implementing the same protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

If I have a few classes which are parsing different websites (1:1 connection between the classes and websites) which are implementing the same protocol (`ParseWebsiteProtocol`) and I want to instantiate the appropriate class based on the `base_url` of the site, how should I do that?
I would make sure that a `parse` func is implemented by all of the classes implementing the protocol, but the classes should not implement the `init` func for all of the different classes because the init should be the same for all classes(?).. Is it possible somehow?

Update:

```swift
enum Sites: String {
    case sitea, siteb, sitec

    func parser(base_url: String) -> Site {
        switch self {
        case .sitea:
            return SiteA(base_url: base_url)
        case .siteb:
            return SiteB(base_url: base_url)
        case .sitec:
            return SiteC(base_url: base_url)
        }
    }
}

protocol ParseWebsiteProtocol {
    func parse(html: HTMLDocument)
}

class SiteBase {
    var doc: HTMLDocument? {didSet {parse(html: doc!)}}

    init(base_url: String) {
        self.doc = try? HTMLDocument(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: base_url)!, options: []))
    }
}

typealias Site = SiteBase & ParseWebsiteProtocol

class SiteA: Site {
    func parse(html: HTMLDocument) {

        }
    }
}

let a = Sites.init(rawValue: "sitea")!.parser(base_url: "sitea.com/subsite")
```

Comment: “I want to instantiate the appropriate class based on the base_url of the site, how should I do that?” With if? Or a switch? What’s the hard part? Show your code to illustrate the difficulty. Personally I’d probably use dependency injection, not separate classes, but it would still need a switch.

Comment: Polymorphism is great for implicitly dispatching messages to the appropriate responders, but it still requires the appropriate responders to have been created in the first place. There's no way to get around that first initial `switch`.

Comment: Yes, this is the first difficulty, to avoid the switch cases because it is well - semi-dynamic if you have expanding number of sites. The second is that how to write common init for the classes implementing the same protocol in a way that not the classes who are having the implementation of the init func but the protocol or some other base class or..?

Comment: And the third one is how to run parse automatically after the page is downloaded.

Comment: If you can bridge to Objective-C, you could use the concept of reflection to find all classes implementing your protocol at runtime, then loop through them to find the one you want to instantiate.  This would avoid using a `switch` and updating your source every time a new derived class is added.  But I'm not sure pure Swift lets you do reflection in this way; Swift's tools are more like 'introspection' than full reflection.